# not all data insert in convert from excell to database

Tags: c#, excel-2007

i have this code:

```
ConnectString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ExcelFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No\"";
        SheetName = SheetName.Substring(0, SheetName.Length - 5);
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection();
        Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectString;
        try {Connection.Open();}
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);
        }
        OleDbDataAdapter Command = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "$]", Connection);
        DataSet ExcelData = new DataSet();
        try {Command.Fill(ExcelData);}
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                Connection.Close();
        }
```

but not all the data in column 1 insert - i get empty data why ?  what can be wrong ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing from Excel, datatypes for the columns are by default guessed based on the contents of the first eight rows. If the values are blank in the first 8 rows for a given column, that can result in no data for the column at all. This can be overridden in the registry. I would suggest investigating that possibility. Here's a good writeup.

http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196

Comment: yes !!! if i sort from the big-to the small value it works excellent
but how i can do it without sorting ?

Comment: update the registry key as described in that post. That will force the provider to read the entire file before assigning data types, so there could be a performance hit if you are dealing with very large files.

Comment: I update the registry key - but still don't work.
maybe because i have Windows 7 ??

Comment: It may be that Windows 7 is looking for the value in a different registry location. I've never debugged this in a Windows 7 environment, but I'll let you know if I come up with anything.